# How can I define an Angular resource that doesn't use query parameters for REST GET?

Tags: rest, angularjs

Currently I have a resource defined in Angular like this:

```
Users: $resource(APIBASEROUTE +'/users/:_id', {_id: '@_id'})
```

When I call for a user with this code:

```
$scope.user = ayApi.Users.get({id:$routeParams.userId});
```

The request is sent as a query parameter like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users?id=526eff826a6100fb22000000
```

However it needs to hit the REST server like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/526eff826a6100fb22000000
```

How do I make Angular do it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the problem is in incosistency of the parameters names.

in definition you have: `{_id:'@_id'})`, it should be the `{id...`

Or in your call it should be with underscore

```
$scope.user = ayApi.Users.get({_id:$routeParams.userId});
```

Any other parameter *(not mapped in the resource definition)* is treated as a query string param. That's why angular decided to append your `id` as a query string part. It is not `_id`

Comment: Doh!  Thank you so much for your sharp eyes!, this has been vexing me for some time.  Glad it was such a silly mistake and not some weirdness in Angular to be dealt with.